# Sagemath is installed into 18.04 but something goes wrong

Tags: sagemath

I have installed Sagemath 8.1 with

```
sudo apt-get install sagemath
```

into Ubuntu 18.04. When I try

```
$ sage
```

I get an error message. It seems that Sagemath lunches but something does not allow it from running. Any ideas?

```
SageMath version 8.1, Release Date: 2017-12-07                     │
│ Type "notebook()" for the browser-based notebook interface.        │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/sagemath/bin/sage-ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from sage.repl.interpreter import SageTerminalApp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage'
```

Comment: How did you installed Sagemath? Please add output of `apt-cache policy sagemath sagemath-common` and `which sage` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert Sorry for my error. I edited my question. I found this here https://ask.sagemath.org/question/44399/installing-sagemath-84-on-wsl-ubuntu-1804/

Comment: Anyway the output of commands above is really needed. Are you running WSL or ordinary normal Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for your kind interest. I am running a normal Ubuntu 18.04 LTS distribution.

Comment: I can recommend to reinstall Sage packages with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall sagemath sagemath-common` and retry.